# Is the 0.6.2 release API compatible with 0.6.0?

Tags: ibm-watson

I assume that 0.6.2 is just an improvement on 0.6.0, but would like to make sure of that.  If my app builds fine with 0.6.0, swapping in 0.6.2 shouldn't cause any compile errors, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've been pretty fast-and-loose with the <1.0 versioning for the [Watson Developer Cloud iOS SDK](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/ios-sdk). The biggest changes between v0.6.0 and v0.6.2 relate to the Conversation service (here's the [commit](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/ios-sdk/commit/14074487ae807245ecee36d279ce3b6424e90a9e)). We tried to only add to the API rather than change it, but might have made minor tweaks along the way that could result in changes to code that uses the Conversation service.